# Combine WPF Expander and GridSplitter and MinHeight

Tags: c#, wpf

How can a `GridSplitter` and an `Expander` be combined nicely, while respecting `MinHeight` of the two areas above / below the `GridSplitter`?

For example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="200" />    <!-- Main -->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />                 <!-- GridSplitter -->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />                 <!-- Expander -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox>
      <ListBoxItem>A</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>...</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

    <Expander Grid.Row="2" Header="Expander" IsExpanded="False">
      <ListBox MinHeight="150">
        <ListBoxItem>X</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>...</ListBoxItem>
      </ListBox>
    </Expander>  
</Grid>
```

If I leave out the `Expander`, the `GridSplitter` works well and respects the `MinHeight` for the two row definitions.

If I leave out the `GridSplitter` (and move the second `MinHeight` to the seconds row definition), the `Expander` works well.

But when both are used, the `MinHeight` is not respected and the `Expander` just doesn't really work anymore.

Is there a simple fix?

Comment: I pasted your XAML into a test project and it seems to work fine, with the Splitter allowing you to resize both controls, however neither goes below their min height. Is there something else affecting it?

Comment: @Rachel I changed the example XAML a bit to make the problem / desired behavior clearer. When the expander is collapse, I want row 2 to "go away". When the expander is open, I want the splitter to resize row 2, but not make it too small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup a trigger on the `RowDefinition` that changes the `MinHeight` based on the Expander state.

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="200" />
        <!-- Main -->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <!-- GridSplitter -->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" >
            <RowDefinition.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type RowDefinition}">
                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="150" /> <!-- Default MinHeight -->
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyExpander, Path=IsExpanded}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="24" /> <!-- MinHeight when Collapsed -->
                            <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="24" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </RowDefinition.Style>
        </RowDefinition>
        <!-- Expander -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem>A</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>...</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

    <Expander x:Name="MyExpander" Grid.Row="2" Header="Expander" IsExpanded="False">
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem>X</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>...</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

By default the Row's MinHeight will be 150, however when the Expander is closed it will have both the Min and Max heights set to 24 (height of a default Expander), forcing its height to stay at the minimum value.

Comment: Nice, but unfortunately collapsing the expander after moving the splitter still doesn't reset Row2. (And the splitter can still resize the row of a collapsed expander.)

Comment: @Peter If you're looking to force the size of the row when it's collapsed, set the `MaxHeight` property using the DataTrigger. In that case, it might be easiest to reverse your trigger, and make the default property setters be the expanded case, and the trigger be the collapsed one. I can update my example if you want.

Comment: Works well after fixing the mismatched `ElementName=parentExpander` / `x:Name="MyExpander"`

Comment: The same technique also works well to set `GridSplitter` `Visibility` to `Collapsed` when the `Expander` is not expanded

Comment: Problem: The control inside the row keeps growing to infinity even though the splitter hits the max height.

Comment: Also adding a default MaxHeight in the style seems to help with the problem mentioned above.